# Querying Zebra printer status using RawPrinterHelper class

Tags: printing, status, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl

I'm using the `RawPrinterHelper` class from Microsoft, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091, to print to a Zebra KR403 printer from C# code, and everything is working fine.

I wish to monitor the status of the printer for paper jams and paper outages. I've found a query that I can send to the printer, "~HQES" or "esc eng 6", that will return everything I need. The problem is that I can not figure out how to send this query to the printer that will allow the printer to respond. The `WritePrinter` in the `RawPrinterHelper` class only seems to return a bool or long type.

I also tried using a `Win32_printer` object to find the `PrinterStatus/PrinterState/Errors` of the printer. using the following method:

```
public static string PrinterStateCheck(string szPrinterName)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}%'", szPrinterName);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        string errorName = "";
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in collection)
        {
            int state = Convert.ToInt32(printer["PrinterState"]);
            errorName = state.ToString();
        }
        return errorName;
```

Utilizing this method, I tried getting the `PrinterState`, `PrinterStatus`, and `DetectedErrorState`, but none of these respond with the information I need. `PrinterState` always returns a `1024`, `PrinterStatus` always returns a `4`, and `DetectedErrorState` always returns a `2`. Though `PrinterState` did return a `0` on a proper printing and `1024` on a paperjam or media out event for a few prints, now it just returns `1024` on every call.

I have also found that Zebra created their own software for monitoring printers on a network. The problem is our printers are not on a network and are only connected to the client computer via USB. Also, we are hoping to check the status of the printer prior to or after each receipt is printed.

I am hoping there is something from the `winspool.Drv` that I can use to send raw data to the printer and receive data back from the printer.

Now I'm using the `ReadPrinter` function of the `winspool.Drv`, but the function is returning `0` which means that a response from the printer cannot be accessed. This usually means that the printer is not setup for bidirectional communication, but I'm  sure that it is. The "Enable bidirectional support" check box is checked in the "Ports" tab of the Printer Properties. Also, the Zebra Setup Utilities can correctly query the printer and receive a response in its Direct Communication window.

Thanks for any advice,

Jeremy

Comment: I haven't done ZPL for a few years...Does Zebra support PJL at all?  If so, you might be able to use that.

Comment: Thanks Douglas. I don't think that this printer (KR403) supports PJL. I'm not sure, but I haven't found any literature saying that it does. I am able to send the ZPL `~HQES` command to the printer, but I can not read the reply from the printer in my code. Currently I am trying to implement `GetPrinterData` as described in [Zebra Language MonitorRC](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7944&actp=LIST), but the program crashes everytime I start the thread.

Comment: After emailing the Zebra support team, I was told that the KR403 printer drivers do not support `GetPrinterData`. It was for a different kiosk printer that Zebra produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem that we ended up utilizing was to create a `WinUSB` driver for the printer. This way the device is treated as a USB device. A `ZebraUSB` object was created using the driver and a method called `WriteRead` was created. Using the `WriteRead` method we sent the `~HQES` query to the printer and received a response. Sometimes there is some lag time between the query and the response. To combat this, we set the response to a variable and retrieve it using a different method.

I'm not sure of the specifics of the code because I did not code the `WinUSB` driver, and I do not have access to its code.

The main point of this answer is that we had to create a `WinUSB` driver for the printer before any of the status queries could work.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something very similar and i can tell you that there is almost no way at all to monitor print jobs in .NET.

I've gotten close though, doing the following:

1. Create a "PrinterDiagnosticsFacade" that queries both the .NET PrintQueue object's status and WMI. Neither are always accurate. Merge the data from both to decide the printer's true status.
2. Adjust the printer's settings so that print jobs stay in the queue. That way you can accurately read the print job's status by doing a WMI query for the print spool jobs. (You can match against the print filename)

Thats how i got close to getting at printer status.

Adding in code to show how its done using the .NET print queue object:

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx for the printqueue object that starts the code off

```
PrintQueue me = Queue; 
if (me != null)
{
    me.Refresh();
    //in this if else,
    //i purposefully put the ones that error out first
    //so that if multiple can be true at the same time
    //the errors will definitely take precedence
    if (me.HasPaperProblem)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Has paper problem");
    }
    else if (me.IsDoorOpened)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Door is open");
    }
    else if (me.IsManualFeedRequired)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Printer needs manually fed");
    }
    else if (me.IsNotAvailable)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Printer not available");
    }

    else if (me.IsOutOfMemory)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Printer is out of memory");
    }
    else if (me.IsOutOfPaper)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Printer is out of paper");
    }
    else if (me.IsOutputBinFull)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Printer output bin is full");
    }
    else if (me.IsPaperJammed)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Error, "Error: Paper jam");
    }
    else if (me.IsOffline)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Offline, "Offline");
    }
    else if (me.IsBusy)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Busy");
    }
    else if (me.IsInitializing)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Initializing");
    }
    else if (me.IsIOActive)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Sending and recieving data");
    }
    else if (me.IsProcessing)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Processing");
    }
    else if (me.IsWarmingUp)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Warming up");
    }
    else if (me.IsPendingDeletion)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Busy, "Deleting a job");
    }
    else if (me.IsPaused)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Paused, "Paused");
    }
    else if (me.IsPrinting)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Printing, "Printing");
    }
    else if (me.IsPowerSaveOn)
    {
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Ready, "In power save mode");
    }
    else
        _SystemDotPrintingStatus = new PrinterStatus(PrinterStatusType.Ready, "Ready");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Micah. I was able to query the WMI object and receive a code, but this did not enable me to receive as much information as the `~HQES` query to the printer would. The `~HQES` query would tell me if the printer was low on paper, if the header was blocked, and information from differing sensors. I'll do some research on this "PrinterDiagnosticFacade", and see what I can find.

Comment: The .NET PrintQueue has a ton of info like that too--check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx to see all the sweet diagnostic bool values you can get from it. Although if you're satisfied with the ~HQES i wouldn't bother with my advice.

Comment: The .NET PrintQueue definitely has some nice bool values. I would try this in conjuction with the WMI `Win32_Printer` object, but I've been moved to a different project now. Is the PrintQueue available if I'm not using `System.Print` for my printing purposes?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. Seems really straight forward to use. I'll give it a try if I'm ever reassigned to that project. I'd +1, but I don't have enough reputation.